# How to create multi-hot encoding from a list column in dataframe?

Tags: keras, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this

```
Label   IDs
    0   [10, 1]
    1   [15]
    0   [14]
```

I want to create a multihot encoding of the feature `IDs`. It should look like this

```
Label ID_10 ID_1 ID_15 ID_14
  0     1     1    0     0
  1     0     0    1     0
  0     0     0    0     1
```

The goal is to use them as features in Keras. So it is also acceptable to make this transformation using a Keras API.

Comment: there is no theoretical problem if it suits your application

Comment: No I am asking how to perform this conversion using pandas or keras APIs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using sklearn's `MultiLabelBinarizer` (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html):

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
mlb.fit(d['IDs'])

new_col_names = ["ID_%s" % c for c in mlb.classes_]

# Create new DataFrame with transformed/one-hot encoded IDs
ids = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(d['IDs']), columns=new_col_names,index=d['IDs'].index)

# Concat with original `Label` column
pd.concat( [d[['Label']], ids], axis=1 )
```